# Mostrar elementos Ocultos en HTML Con js

Tags: javascript, html

Cordial Saludo.

Lo que deseo hacer es lo siguiente:

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
 <div  class="field">

  <label for="name">Codigo Coordinador<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <div class="inputs">
   <select class="aweform" id="CodigoCordinador" name="CodigoCordinador" required type="text">
    <option>Andres12</option>
    <option>Jose22</option>
    <option>Hola22</option>
    <option>Prueba22</option>
      </select>
  </div>  
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <label for="email">Cedula<span class="required" onkeypress="return valida(event)">*</span></label>
  <div class="inputs" onkeypress="return valida(event)">
   <input class="aweform" id="Cedula" name="Cedula" required onkeypress="return valida(event)" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>  
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <label for="phone">Telefono<span class="required" onkeypress="return valida(event)">*</span></label>
  <div class="inputs" onkeypress="return valida(event)">
   <input class="aweform" id="Telefono" name="Telefono" required onkeypress="return valida(event)" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>  
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <label for="subject">Total Devengado<span class="required" onkeypress="return valida(event)">*</span></label>
  <div class="inputs" onkeypress="return valida(event)">
   <input class="aweform" id="TotalDevengado" name="TotalDevengado" required  onkeypress="return valida(event)" type="text"/>
  </div>  
 </div>
 <div class="field">
  <label for="phone">Tiene Pago Vacaciones</label>
  <div class="inputs">
   <select class="aweform" id="PagosVa" name="PagosVa">
    <option></option>
    <option>SI</option>
    <option>NO</option>
   </select>
   <input class="aweform" id="PagosVacacionales" name="PagosVacacionales" type="text"/>
  </div>  
 </div>

  <div class="field">
  <label for="phone">Tiene Pagos Adicionales</label>
  <div class="inputs">
   <select class="aweform" id="PagosAdi" name="PagosAdi">
    <option></option>
    <option>SI</option>
    <option>NO</option>
   </select>
   <input class="aweform" id="PagosAdicionales" name="PagosAdicionales" type="text">
  </div>  
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <label for="subject">Total Descontado<span class="required" onkeypress="return valida(event)">*</span></label>
  <div class="inputs" onkeypress="return valida(event)">
   <input class="aweform" id="TotalDescontado" name="TotalDescontado" required onkeypress="return valida(event)" type="text"/>
   <br>
  </div> 

  <input type="button" id="limpiar" onclick="limpiarFormulario();" class="myButton" value="Limpiar">


  <input type="submit" name="Validar" id="validar" class="myButton2" value="Validar">
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de dar click en validar: se muestre lo siguiente que esta oculto:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#limpiar').click(function(){

              $('#desprendible').show();

          });
      });  


  </script>
   <div class="desprendible" id="desprendible" style="display: none">

              <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="Usuario">
              <input type="text" id="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
              <input type="button" id="btn-cancelar" Value="Cancelar">
              <input type="button" id="btn-enviar" Value="Enviar">

          </div>


</form>
```

No se como hacer que funcione.

Espero me puedan ayudar Por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo modifique el selector el cual debe de mostrar el formulario, lo cambie de `#limpiar` a `#validar` en el evento click, pruebalo y me me dices:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#validar').click(function(){

        $('#desprendible').show();

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="field">

  <label for="name">Codigo Coordinador<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <div class="inputs">
   <select class="aweform" id="CodigoCordinador" name="CodigoCordinador" required type="text">
    <option>Andres12</option>
    <option>Jose22</option>
    <option>Hola22</option>
    <option>Prueba22</option>
      </select>
  </div>  
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <label for="email">Cedula<span class="required" onkeypress="return valida(event)">*</span></label>
  <div class="inputs" onkeypress="return valida(event)">
   <input class="aweform" id="Cedula" name="Cedula" required onkeypress="return valida(event)" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>  
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <label for="phone">Telefono<span class="required" onkeypress="return valida(event)">*</span></label>
  <div class="inputs" onkeypress="return valida(event)">
   <input class="aweform" id="Telefono" name="Telefono" required onkeypress="return valida(event)" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>  
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <label for="subject">Total Devengado<span class="required" onkeypress="return valida(event)">*</span></label>
  <div class="inputs" onkeypress="return valida(event)">
   <input class="aweform" id="TotalDevengado" name="TotalDevengado" required  onkeypress="return valida(event)" type="text"/>
  </div>  
 </div>
 <div class="field">
  <label for="phone">Tiene Pago Vacaciones</label>
  <div class="inputs">
   <select class="aweform" id="PagosVa" name="PagosVa">
    <option></option>
    <option>SI</option>
    <option>NO</option>
   </select>
   <input class="aweform" id="PagosVacacionales" name="PagosVacacionales" type="text"/>
  </div>  
 </div>

  <div class="field">
  <label for="phone">Tiene Pagos Adicionales</label>
  <div class="inputs">
   <select class="aweform" id="PagosAdi" name="PagosAdi">
    <option></option>
    <option>SI</option>
    <option>NO</option>
   </select>
   <input class="aweform" id="PagosAdicionales" name="PagosAdicionales" type="text">
  </div>  
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <label for="subject">Total Descontado<span class="required" onkeypress="return valida(event)">*</span></label>
  <div class="inputs" onkeypress="return valida(event)">
   <input class="aweform" id="TotalDescontado" name="TotalDescontado" required onkeypress="return valida(event)" type="text"/>
   <br>
  </div> 

  <input type="button" id="limpiar" onclick="limpiarFormulario();" class="myButton" value="Limpiar">


  <input type="submit" name="Validar" id="validar" class="myButton2" value="Validar">
  



<div class="desprendible" id="desprendible" style="display: none">

   <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="Usuario">
   <input type="text" id="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
   <input type="button" id="btn-cancelar" Value="Cancelar">
   <input type="button" id="btn-enviar" Value="Enviar">

</div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Amigo, Ya funcionó